# Woocommerce - Add extra content to email depending on if variations/add ons purchased

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add some text to the processing email sent to customers if that customer has purchased an add-on or certain product variation. I am using the Woocommerce email customiser plugin and that lets me drop a hook like woocommerce_email_order_meta on a certain email. So I added this to the processing order mail.

In fuctions.php I started by adding any text to the hook woocommerce_email_order_meta so it would appear on the mail. And this worked. I change this text to display the contents of wc_display_item_meta and this worked. I then tried to add code to check if a certain phase (Installation Service) is contained in the wc_display_item_meta and echo something if it’s there and something else if it’s not. And this didn’t work. The result was it echo’s the contents of wc_display_item_meta and always says no addon include, even when Installation Service text is showing in the output of the wc_display_item_meta on the mauk.

So I am thinking am going wrong where I try to find the text in wc_display_item_meta or am I trying to get a value from wc_display_item_meta before it’s there?

````
function add_message_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $output = ""; // Declare the output variable

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $key => $item ) :
        $product = $order->get_product_from_item($item);
        $variant_name = ($item['variation_id']) ? wc_get_product($item['variation_id']) : '';
        $item_meta = wc_display_item_meta( $item );

        // Concatenate the output to the variable
        $output .= $item_meta;
    endforeach;
    
    // Check if "Installation Service" is present in the output variable
    if ( stripos( $output, 'Installation Service' ) !== false ) {
        // "Installation Service" was found, so display the "addon included" message
        echo "addon included";
    } else {
        // "Installation Service" was not found, so display the "no addon include" message
        echo "no addon include";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_message_to_email', 10, 4 );```
````

Comment: Use `$item_meta = wc_display_item_meta( $item, ['echo' => false] );`

Comment: Amazing, Works perfectly. I didn't expect the fix to be so easy, i was looking for bigger issues. Thanks so much saved me lots of time.